# Python - Searcing MixedCase with regex

Tags: python, regex, string, case, mixed

I wonder if someone could help me solving this problem, I've tried this 2 regex but no success. I wonder if I'm doing wrong anywhere in the expression?

```
string[1] = "MixEdCasE"
string[2] = "MiXeD CaSE"    
re.search("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$", string[num])
re.search(r'(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$', string[num])
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @AmineHajyoussef just trying to built a moderator function with regex

Comment: Why not just search for `[a-z][A-Z]`?

Comment: @Jack You know what, I didn't thought of that. Aiyayaya I'm always making things complicated -__- . Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

This pattern works well:

```
re.search(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}$', string[num])
```

The problem is that your example strings contain more than 8 characters.

Comment: Tried to increased it, but still no luck

Comment: @Natsume: with this pattern you must have exactly 8 characters. to allow more replace `{8}` by `{8,}`

Comment: still no luck either. 
`>>> re.search(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$', "MixEdCasE")
>>>
`

Comment: @Natsume: `MixEdCasE` doesn't contain digits.